# html adding borders

Tags: html, border

I would like to add some right-positioned borders to my menu.
But the ones that I can use by default are not working for me. Can anyone recommend where to get a bit better looking borders, and how i add them in the css?

Comment: What have you tried already? Perhaps set up an example as jsfiddle.net that we can look at...

Comment: could you provide some code and/or a better description of what you want to achieve? Because it sounds like `border-right: 1px solid black` isn#t what you are searching..

Answer (score 0):

the css style you need :

```
#mymenu
{
border-right:solid 50px red;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try using [jQuery](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) (its more shape than actual border)

There's also a set of jQuery [plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-corners-borders/) to use on top of that.

Finally, there are some nice and easy [css3](http://designshack.net/articles/introduction-to-css3-part-2-borders) border properties that you could use.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If I had to guess it would be the use of jQuery, plugins and CSS3 when just normal CSS would (depending on what he actually wants) work...

Comment: I will be suprised if someone comes up with an answer which does not use one of these technologies. CSS is very limited unless you photoshop your own images and CSS3 has a lot of qualities that previous CSS does not have. Considering how abrupt the question was, this is a brilliant answer.

Comment: To be fair in 7 questions he's not accepted a single answer and most of them don't make any sense so fair play for trying.